# 405 Method is not allowed on Django Form POST

Tags: python, django, csv

Everytime I click Submit button on my POST form to upload a CSV file. I get a code 405 Method not allowed. I already tried changing other importing methods like django_import_export but still I got the same response (405). Please help!

This is my views.py:

```
class AdvisoryView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'advisory.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["adv"] = Mobile.objects.all()
        return context

    def mobile_upload(request):
        template = "advisory.html"

        prompt = {
            'order': 'blah'
        }

        if request.method == "GET":
            return render(request, template, prompt)

        csv_file = request.FILES('file')

        if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
            messages.error(request, 'This is not a csv file')

        data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
        io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
        next(io_string)
        for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar='|'):
            _, created = Mobile.objects.update_or_create(
                mobile_owner=column[0],
                mobile_number=column[1],
            )
        context = {}
        return render(request, template, prompt)
```

and mobile.html looks like this. I actually put the form inside a model form.

```
<div class="modal-body">            
    {% block content %}
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <p>Only accepts .csv file</p>
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
    {% endblock content %}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
```

and the urls.py is

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from .views import AdvisoryView, HomeView


urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('advisory/', AdvisoryView.as_view(), name='advisory'),
]
```

Comment: Can you please post the full error traceback you get (edit your post with it)?

Comment: @KJTHoward, I getting redirected to a *This page isn’t workingIf the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405* after I click submit and no data inserted

Comment: if you run with `$ python manage.py runserver 0:8090` you should see some output on the command line. Did you test it?

Comment: when I run $ python manage.py runserver, it response 200 code, but when I do the inserting form. command line output will be "POST /advisory/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Comment: OK, status 405 is of the http protocol, so you probably won't get a traceback from python. One thing confuses me: you shouldn't have `request.method == "GET":` on a upload request. In the template you have method POST. That somehow doesn't fit together. Usually it isn't required to distinguish the request methods in your rendering view

Comment: What makes you think that your `mobile_upload()` method would be automagically invoked when posting to this view ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views

Comment: This problem is easily solvable if you are using function-based views instead of class-based.

Answer (score 0):

This answer has explained why POST is not allowed in TemplateView.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44859716/11607969

You may need to change your function `mobile_upload` to `post` .

Comment: I tried this, now I'm getting `TypeError: post() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
[12/Mar/2020 00:44:29] "POST /advisory/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78494`

Comment: The format of using POST in a class view is `def post(self, request):`.

Comment: you should also consider to do a redirect to a success or error page on the end of the post method

Comment: still not working, im getting `'MultiValueDict' object is not callable` error. im really stuck here for almost 4 days haha